# Demailly condition in Analytical algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

**Grauert-Riemenschneider conjecture**: If a compact complex manifold $X$ possesses a smooth Hermitian line bundle which is semi-positive everywhere and positive on an open dense set, then $X$ is Moishezon

or in another words

Let $Y$ be a compact irreducible analytic space. The conjecture of Grauert and Riemenschneider says that $Y$ is a Moishezon space if and only if it has a desingularisation $\pi:X\to Y$ which admits a quasipositive holomorphic line bundle.

Demailly gave a nice proof for this theorem via asymptotic Morse inequality by inspiring the work of  [Edward Witten](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214437492).(For more information See [Y.T.Siu survey paper](https://eudml.org/doc/110067) in Séminaire Bourbaki 1985 or Bismut's amazing [new proof](https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~bismut/Bismut/1987.pdf) by using heat flow)

$$\dim H^0(X,L^k)\geq k^n\int_{X(\leq 1)}(\sqrt{-1}\Theta(L))^n+O(k^n)$$

**[Demailly's theorem](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/riemenschneider.pdf)**:(It is equivalent to Siu's theorem) Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold
of dimension $n$ and $L$ a line bundle over $X$. Assume that 
$$\chi=\int_{X(\leq 1)}(\sqrt{-1}\Theta(L))^n>0$$

Then $X$ is Moishezon. Here $X(\leq 1)$ is the open set where
the curvature $\sqrt{-1}\Theta(L)$ is non-degenerate and has at most one negative eigenvalue.

Bonavero showed that $L$ admit singular Hermitian metric $h$ with at worst analytical singularities such that $\chi(L,h)>0$

My question is: what does Demailly's condition $\chi>0$ correspond to in analytical algebraic geometry?

Comment: In fact we know $\dim H^0(X,L^k)=a_0k^n+a_1k^{n-1}+...$ where $a_0=Vol(X)$ and $a_1 = \frac{-K_X.L^{n-1}}{2(n-1)!}$

Comment: I don't think it corresponds to an invariant in algebraic geometry. As Demailly himself says, in his lecture note "Multiplier ideal sheaves and analytic methods in algebraic geometry", "One difficulty in the application of these inequalities is that the curvature integral is in general quite uneasy to compute, since it is neither a topological nor an algebraic invariant".

Comment: Also, $a_0$ is not the $L$-volume of $X$ in general. It is only if $L$ is big and nef.

Comment: @diverietti Thank you, I changed to Demailly condition.

Comment: I don't know which kind of correspondence you are looking for, maybe you should expand a little bit more to explain in which direction you are looking. Anyway, of course, this condition implies that $L$ is big.

Comment: For example see conjecture 1.1 http://www.numdam.org/article/AIF_2015__65_3_1367_0.pdf